# Ethernet interface automatically re-enables after disabling manually

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, interface

I am trying to manually disable the eth0 interface, which should persist until the system is either rebooted or by manually enabling it. Unfortunately by either using

```
ip link set dev eth0 down
```

or

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

the interface is down for a moment, around 2 to 15 seconds and than automatically starts enabling itself, giving the following message:

```
fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [Atheros 8031 ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=2188000.ethernet:00, irq=-1)
[  727.204693] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

When plugging the ethernet cable out of the machine, the eth0 down does persist.

After trying to do it with the commandline method, I also tried to dig into the ethernet driver based on this link: http://www.6by9.net/using-linux-sys-to-disable-ethernet-hardware-devices/

But unfortunately there appears to be no "remove" file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by commenting out the following lines

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```